# Passing data between ViewControllers versus doing local Fetch in each VC

Tags: core-data, uiviewcontroller, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm developing an iPhone app using Core Data and I'm looking for some general advice and recommendations on whether its acceptable to pass data between ViewControllers versus doing a local fetch in each ViewController as you navigate to it. Ordinarily I would say it all depends on various factors (e.g. performance etc) but the passing data approach is so prevalent in my app and I'm spooked by all the stories about Apple rejecting apps because of not conforming to their standard guidelines.

So let me put another way -- is it non-standard to pass data between VC's?

The reason I pass data so much is because each ViewController is just another view on to data present in my object model / graph. Once I have a handle on my first object in the first view controller (which I of course do have to fetch), I can use the existing object composition /  relationships to drill down into the next level of detail into data and so I just pass these objects to the next VC.

Separately, one possible downside with this passing-data-to-each-VC approach is I don't benefit from (what I perceive to be) the optimisation/benefits that NSFetchedResultsController provides in terms of efficient memory usage and section handling. My app is read-only but I do have one table with 5000 rows and I'm curious if I am missing out on NSFetchedResultsController benefits. Any thoughts on this as well? Can I somehow still benefit from NSFetchedResultsController goodness without having to do a full fetch (as I would have already passed in the data from my previous VC)?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not only standard to pass data down but it is the recommend way to do it.

It is called dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks Marcus. I also read your VERY helpful tutorial on this subject and felt much better. Link below for other people's benefit.

http://www.mac-developer-network.com/articles/cd0004.html